# const variable declaration in javaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6

I have learned somewhere that variables declared using `const` throw error when reassigned. But inside a loop it works just fine.

For example;

```
for(let i=0; i<allItems.length; i++){
    const item = allItems[i]
    item.innerText = "Yayy"
}
```

This works fine, and does not throws error, eventhough item is reassigned multiple times.
Can someone clarify why this happens.

Comment: You are not reassigning what `item` points to; you are merely changing a property of `item`.  What item is pointing to can be changed/mutated, but if you were to try `item = 3` you would get an error.

Comment: @Phil - at a glance I also expected this to be a scope question, but actually the OP is confused regarding the difference between assignment and mutation; this probably should be closed for some different reason.

Comment: `const` is block-scoped. It can only be declared / defined / assigned once in a particular block

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'd wait for OP to clarify. They specifically pointed out the `for` loop as the source of confusion

Comment: @Phil - fair; on second read you're probably correct.  Sorry about that.